# How to make ssh account capabele to only sshfs and rsync?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sshd, sshfs

I'd like to make ssh account that is capable of doing two things:

- mounting (can be one) directory via `sshfs`
- performing backup&recovery of his/her desired directories using `rsync`

I would love to utilize `ssh` for `rsync` purpose, without running extra `rsync` server. (Main issue is availability of one port just for `ssh`. If not possible or simplifies things a lot I might consider `sshfs` tunnelling).

**Question:** so far I achieved `sftp` only accounts. However they lack of `rsync` over `ssh`, which I'd like to add.

**TL;DR:** so far, I've tried to join "ftp only" account approach with "allowed commands wrapper" approach via custom script pointed by `ForceCommand`option - those details are described below.

## How I achieved `sftp` only account so far

So far I had success with configuring `ssh` account to be limited to `sftp` following tutorial : https://solderintheveins.co.uk/2011/03/ubuntu-sftp-only-account-how-to/

In digest, it was mainly achieved by following `sshd_config` change:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group sftponly
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

And making account belonging only to `sftponly` group:

```
username=LIMITED_USER
sudo useradd -d /home/${username} -s /usr/lib/sftp-server -M -N -g sftponly ${username}
sudo passwd ${username}
sudo mkdir -p /home/${username}/uploads /home/${username}/.ssh
sudo chown ${username}:sftponly /home/${username}/uploads /home/${username}/.ssh
sudo chmod 700 /home/${username}/.ssh
```

Added `/usr/lib/sftp-server` to `/etc/shells`.

As users have encrypted home directories in Ubuntu Server style, I have their authorized keys in different location ( via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` , `AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/users_configs/%u/authorized_keys` ) :

```
sudo mkdir /etc/ssh/users_configs/${username}
cd /etc/ssh/users_configs/${username}
sudo vim /etc/ssh/users_configs/${username}/authorized_keys
# Here copy desired signature for the purpose from the client
sudo chmod 700 /etc/ssh/users_configs/${username}/authorized_keys
sudo chown ${username}:sftponly /etc/ssh/users_configs/${username}/authorized_keys
```

## Problems with `rsync` and so far tries with "ForceCommand"

While mounting via `sshfs` works fine,
I came across following problem:
how to allow user to also `rsync`?

I tried to drop `ChrootDirectory` and change `ForceCommand` to some kind of "command filter" (i.e. allowing only subset of commands) like in : https://binblog.info/2008/10/20/openssh-going-flexible-with-forced-commands/ :

```
$ grep -B 1 ForceCommand  /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Match group sftponly
    ForceCommand /etc/ssh/wrapper.sh
$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/wrapper.sh
#!/bin/sh
(
echo -n '# '
date
echo $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
) >> /home/"${USER}"/.ssh_commands_history
case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
    "allowed_command")
        eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
        ;;
    *)
        echo ERROR;
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
$ sudo touch /home/LIMITED_USER/.ssh_commands_history
$ sudo chown LIMITED_USER:sftponly /home/LIMITED_USER/.ssh_commands_history
$ sudo chmod 0700 /home/LIMITED_USER/.ssh_commands_history
```

but after all it does not pan out. ( I perform `ssh u@srv ps` and it get's stuck instead of returning output of ps as in mentioned example. `sshd -ddd` nor `ssh -v` seem helpful here ).

Therefore:
I'd like to make accounts that will be used for `sshfs` and `rsyncing`. How to make them working and limited for increased security?

Answer (score 1):

`ForceCommand` is **not** filter, but forced command regardless the command-line as the name proposes. `rsync` requires to run different commands (as far as I know ... yes, `sshd -ddd` and `ssh -vvv` would be helpful to provide).

One possibility is to leave the `ChrootDirectory`, remove `ForceCommand` and copy `rsync`, maybe some `shell` and it's dependencies (`ldd /usr/bin/rsync`) to the `chroot`. It is not ideal, but it should do the job and fence the user from the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I've found where problem was!

When I've created wrapper script, I've missed that it's in bash, and that through other tutorial, I've set the default shell to be `/usr/lib/sftp-server`.

Afterwards, wrapper script started to work and I logged which commands I need to allow.

Solution:

1.reverted shell (from `/usr/lib/sftp-server`), so wrapper could work: `usermod -s /bin/bash LIMITED_USER`

2.added appropriate allowed commands to wrapper script

```
'internal-sftp')
/usr/lib/sftp-server
;;
'/bin/true' \
|'rsync --server --sender -logDtpre.iLsfxC . /home/LIMITED_USER' \
|'rsync --server --sender -vlogDtpre.iLsfxC . /home/LIMITED_USER')
eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND 2>>${LOGFILE}
exit $?
;;
```

For exact commands you might want to allow, e.g. rsync commands, just try them to run, and later copy from `/user/LIMITED_USER/.ssh_commands_history` where they are logged by wrapper script.

P.S. I've made this a community wiki, so I hope this could become more useful to others who might like to make sshfs+rsync capable and limited ssh accounts.