# Can I use `internal-sftp` when using wrapper script with `ForceCommand` in sshd?

Tags: ssh, chroot, sftp

I [use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278548/9689) `/etc/ssh/wrapper.sh` script, like in [tutorial](https://binblog.info/2008/10/20/openssh-going-flexible-with-forced-commands/), that filters which commands are allowed to be run via `ssh` and logs them.

Currently when `internal-sftp` is required, I use `/usr/lib/sftp-server`.

Is there a way I could run `internal-sftp` of `ssh` binary, maybe even with chroot, instead of `/usr/lib/sftp-server`? (e.g. via some `ssh` command line flags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `internal-sftp` is evaluated inside of `sshd` server. If you use wrapper script as `ForceCommand` already, you can't go back. Even if you could, in `chroot` you don't have the `sshd` binary either.

Unfortunately, `ForceCommand` different from `internal-sftp` blocks even the `sftp` subsystem (subsystem is internally handled as a command).

Only way to do that is to copy `sftp-server` into `chroot` and run it from there (again with all dependent shared objects and so).